# Having Difficulty Merging Dataframes on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to merge two `dataframes` of hockey data, both have player names (what I am trying to merge on) mind you the one with salary data only has 500 rows or so and the primary `dataframe` has 2000+ (if that makes a difference. Trying to merge them on name when applicable and the new df created has no rows of data in it.

Wanted to merge wherever it made sense to (ie. where both had salary data for a given player)

Let me know if something is not clear or how to upload more info as needed as I'm not seeing an option to make uploading the tables possible or if I can otherwise include more insight/info that may make my situation clearer to you when trying to help.

Thanks for what input you can kindly provide, enjoy your weekend.

[Dataframes I am looking to merge on player names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maGeq.png)

When trying to merge the `dataframes`, I am simply trying to do so as follows

```
df = pd.merge(hdf, sdf, on='Player')
```

Comment: Hi Just Drew It. Please share an example of the dataframes instead of just a picture, it is much easier then to help. Looking into the dataframes, I can see that the first has a normal index, whereas the second has `Player` as the index. Perhaps changing the index on `hdf` may work, by doing: `hdf.set_index('Player', inplace = True)`

Answer (score 0):

First reset sdf index cause now player name is index not a column:

```
df = pd.merge(hdf, sdf.reset_indx(), on='Player')
```